# What does it mean that a mutual fund is some percentage "short in cash" or "long in cash"?

Tags: investment-strategies, asset-allocation

http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=PTTRX&region=usa&culture=en-US

Trying to understand this fund as I'm learning more about it.

I don't understand this: What does it mean when it's 66.44% short in cash? I think 16.12% long in cash means it holds 16.12% of the portfolio in cash, but what is short cash? Can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: http://markovprocesses.com/blog/2014/03/pimco_quant_approach/ has some interesting analysis on PTTRX while it does not necessarily officially lever it's fund may still behave that way.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

See how the fund shows the % net? It simply means that $100 in assets is actually $150 in Bonds and Other, with $50 borrowed to do so.

As of Aug 2015, this anomaly appears to be gone, they are now net long bonds and cash positions.